# GMSPlacePickerViewController editting (GooglePlacePicker)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, gmsplacepicker

I am trying to work with the Google Place Picker API
(https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/placepicker)

I and want to edit a few things when the modal PlacePicker view appears. 
For example the 'Title' should be either another language or set by me. Or generally edit navigation bar (left button etc).

I would also like to change the mapStyle ?

Comment: Perhaps you can make a custom class which subclasses the **GMSPlacePickerViewController** and then you can change the details

Comment: Im still not sure what to do with that  - is there a method I should override ?